# ServiceUnavailable error in cypher statement from guides.neo4j.com/wiki

Tags: neo4j, websocket, wikipedia

I recently created a Neo4j sandbox instance (blank) so I could test https://guides.neo4j.com/wiki.

Using https://guides.neo4j.com/wiki, I had success running the first cypher statement to populate the graph with Wikipedia categories. However, the second cypher statement produces an error - after running for a few seconds.

Here's the statement:

```
UNWIND range(0,4) as level
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt("
MATCH (c:Category { pagesFetched: false, level: $level })
CALL apoc.load.json('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtype=page&cmtitle=Category:' + apoc.text.urlencode(c.catName) + '&cmprop=ids%7Ctitle&cmlimit=500')
YIELD value as results
UNWIND results.query.categorymembers AS page
MERGE (p:Page {pageId: page.pageid})
ON CREATE SET p.pageTitle = page.title, p.pageUrl = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + apoc.text.urlencode(replace(page.title, ' ', '_'))
WITH p,c
MERGE (p)-[:IN_CATEGORY]->(c)
WITH DISTINCT c
SET c.pagesFetched = true", { level: level }) YIELD value
RETURN value
```

And here's the error message:

```
Error ServiceUnavailable
WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3
```

The js console shows error message:

```
neo4j-web.min.js:20 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

I also posted this on the neoj4 Slack channel and the neo4j Google group - any help is appreciated.

As an addendum to this post (5/25/2018):

I installed neo4j community edition version 3.4.0 on an AWS EC2 (Linux) instance, and did not get the ServiceUnavailable error as above. The error occurred on my MacBook Pro macos 10.13.4

Thanks for your interest.

Colin Goldberg